# OpenCV with Visual Studio 2015 ( msvcr120d.dll error )

Tags: opencv, dll, linker, visual-studio-2015

I have tried to link **OpenCV** with **VS Express 2015** as I was doing in VS 2013 but I got `msvcr120d.dll error`. It says that this `.dll was not found in my system.`

Any Ideas of how I can link OpenCV with VS 2015 Express?

Comment: It seems like it still requires _VS2k13_ (_Debug_ mode). You need to recompile the sources from scratch using _VS2k15_ tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prebuild Libs are only for VS11 and VS12 this is Visual studio 2012 and 2013. You can build and release your own OpenCV libs for Visual Studio 2015 comm. edition. 
Just use this tutorial 
[Install OpenCV Visual Studio 2015](http://funvision.blogspot.com/2015/11/install-opencv-visual-studio-2015.html)

Comment: Opencv 3.1 now support VC14 lib. Just download opencv for windows from main page. Extract the opencv and use standard tutorials install opencv on windows: Instalation by using prebuild libs. Before you include header files you have to set enviromentall path by setx -m OPENCV_DIR command and in enviromental variables Path editor just set %OPENCV_DIR%\bin the folder where is DLLs are located.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make the OpenCV Debug configuration working in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition by installing Visual Studio 2013 Express on my system. As the result, the file msvcr120d.dll appeared in Windows\System32, and after the reboot of the computer I was able to debug OpenCV example in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I also did the same way and it worked for me as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Installed Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition on a different machine and then copied the dlls msvcp120d.dll and msvcr120d.dll into Windows\System32\ of my work machine.  Worked a treat for opencv 2.4 x64 development.

This is not required for opencv 3+ as there are vs14 binaries available.

-- edit 23/8/16-- 
Not working so well, actually.  Runtime errors arising in msvcr120d.dll when vectors containing opencv objects including Mat and KeyPoint are deconstructed, or are constructed using a large reserve.